# Using figma animations in JavaScript

Tags: frontend, figma

I am totally confused on how to use the animations made in figma to use in a front-end app like a loading spinner, exporting SVGs are easy but how to export a whole animated SVG or I have to animate it with CSS or JS???

Answer (score 1):

In figma the animations are actually transitions.
You can't "export" animations and just add them. But you can copy some parts of the animation code for CSS.

In the edit mode of figma, you can see how the animation is created. But first look
If it is animated in figma: In the inspect tab (right sidebar) look for Interactions, there you will find transition, duration and more info to use when you animate it.
Here is an example on what animation details you can copy:

```
// On drag
// Navigate to: "Frame 2";
// Animate: Smart animate;
animation-timing-function: ease-out;
animation-duration: 300ms;
```

Comment: Is there any way I can at least get the gif of the animation like a loading spinner??

Comment: I suggest that you export the image from the loading spinner and use CSS to rotate it.

If the designer imported the loading spinner as a gif, then you can export it. And if you haven't already, try out plugins in figma, maybe there is already a plugin for what you need.
Maybe look at the figma documentation as well to find out how the design file is constructed, also I don't know if the designer used special plugins to create the animation.

Comment: @Jasmin I can you help me with this? I have created a text animation and I'm quite new to figma, I want this animation on my website, I tried plugins, I screenrecord but it destory the quality of text, <iframe> could work but its take forever to load.
https://www.figma.com/embed?embed_host=share&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.figma.com%2Fproto%2FT9BkhCiWnNWh2xsrFTPZ4S%2FmyName%3Fnode-id%3D2%253A2%26scaling%3Dmin-zoom%26page-id%3D0%253A1

Comment: @ArshErgon sorry for the late reply. It's a simple animation, you can do it with HTML, CSS and JS.
Since you change content, use JS. I
 don't recommend using a gif for text, because it loads longer and it's not accessible (for Search engines too). 

So if you know JavaScript, you should have no problem to animate it yourself. Here is the same animation in JQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782056/i-want-my-text-change-animation-in-javascript-to-have-smooth-transition 
change the speed, content and add color (for example change class for color)  :)